# css properties adaptation of elements to the page

Tags: html, css

know if there is any css property to resize the elements of a web page according to the height/width of it? i tried with the nowrap property and setting the height to 90vh but i failed

```css
height: 90vh;
white-space: nowrap;
```

that is, if I resize the browser window, all the elements are still displayed but reduced

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `media queries`

e.g.:
`@media screen and (max-width: 500px) { ... }` to style elements when the width of the browser or device is below 500px

`@media screen and (min-width: 500px) { ... }` to style elements when the screen is at least 500px or bigger

You can also use min/max height. Read more about media queries here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_media_query_breakpoints.asp

```css
div {
  width:300px;
  height:300px}


@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
 div {
    background-color: blue
  }

}


@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  div {
    background-color: red
  }
}
```

```html
Make your browser window smaller to see the div change color

<div></div>
```